# React: How to add property by mapping fetch response

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to add a **'active'** property to an element I'm fetching from an API that does not have that property originally.
Whenever I console.log the item afterwards it gives the correct ID (originally in the API), but **'active'** is undefined

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchList = async () => {
      try {
        const request = await fetch(URL);
        const response = await request.json();
        response.map((user) => ({ ...user, active: true }));
        setUserList(response);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchList();
  }, []);
```

```
return <div onClick={() => console.log(user.id, user.active)}></div>
```

Comment: `map()` does return a new array, it doesn't change it.

Comment: it's still undefined after I changed it to forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` returns new array and  you have forget to assign result of `response.map((user) => ({ ...user, active: true }));` so you have to assign map result to any variable like

```
const updatedResponse = response.map((user) => ({ ...user, active: true }));
```

You can use following but for it you have to use `let` for `response` in place of const otherwise you will get type error of assignment of const variable

```
response = response.map((user) => ({ ...user, active: true }));
```